# Using React Context for Internationalization

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, higher-order-components

I know from doing a fair amount of research that internationalization/localization is one of the few legitimate use cases for React's [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) feature. However my question is about whether one really *needs* to use context. Wouldn't it work just as well to wrap the components to be internationalized in a higher-order component that provides the localization strings as a prop? e.g. for an app that supports English and Spanish:

```
// WithLocale.js
import React from 'react';

import en from './locales/en-US.json';
import es from './locales/es-ES.json';

const locales = {'en-US': en, 'es-ES': es};

let currentLocale = (navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0])
    || navigator.language
    || navigator.userLanguage
    || 'en-US';

const WithLocale = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return (props) => {
            const locale = { strings: locales[currentLocale] };
            return <WrappedComponent {...props} locale={locale} />
    }
};

export default WithLocale;
```

With localization JSON such as:

```
// en.json
{
  "header": "My App",
  "description": "This is an internationalizated app in React",
}
```

And a really basic example of how it could be used in a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import WithLocale from './WithLocale';

const SubComponent = (props) => (
        <div>
            <p className="App-intro">
                {props.locale.strings.description}
            </p>
        </div>
);

SubComponent.propTypes = {
    locale: PropTypes.object
};

export default WithLocale(SubComponent);
```

The main issue I can think of is the overhead of injecting a potentially large JSON into every component that needs one of the strings. Are there any other reasons that this solution is not preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no penalty caused by using large localization structure as one of the `props` of your `Component`. Because objects are not passed by value, rather the reference to the object is being copied. So there is not an issue to be concerned about.

The real issue is that when your are not using `context` you'll have to pass your localization all the way from root `Component` to the most bottom one. Event if your intermediate `Components` do not care about localization they'll still have to accept localization props and pass them further.

That's why people use `context`: to make intermediate `Components` totally unaware of some stuff used by `Components` which are lower in the hierarchy.

**UPDATE.** Your solution with `WithLocale` will work, though there is an issue with forcing `Components` to redraw when switching locale. You'll have to update `currentLocale` in two places: inside `WithLocale.js` and in your root `Component`. Apart from that I don't see any possible disadvantages compared to using `context`.

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping the export for the child component in the `WithLocale` HoC solve the problem of passing the localization props through intermediate components? The issue I was foreseeing is that my example will result in the creation of many localization objects the more components I wrap in `WithLocale`

Comment: @DTetik updated the answer. Created object will be really small, i.e. `{ strings: reference-to-locales }`. I wouldn't care too much about them.

Comment: Thank you - if I'm not mistaken you can force an update at the root level to deal with the problem of redrawing. Not a big deal as the locale should not change too much in a session. But there's also the issue of dealing with the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method which can prevent changes (be it with props or context). I'll address this in a future question